# execv unknown path usage

Tags: c, unix, exec

I have to execute a command whose path is unknown. I can reach the environment paths, but how can I use them? For example if there are 5 distinct paths, which one I should try in execv ?

/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

After parsing these paths in an array, how can I use them? Should I try execv for each of them?

Comment: All of them? Separate them, append the program name and call `execv`. If you get an error repeat with the next path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use `execvp`, which searches for the binary in the executing shell's `PATH` (see http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_execv.htm).

If that's not an option, you should probably do the same as `execvp` / the shell does: Look at one path after another (left to right) and check if there's an executable with the given name in there.

Comment: I know, I heard it but I must use execv, its a dummy school project

Comment: @user1471821 iirc `execvp()` basically tries to find the binary in and then `execv()`s it - check e.g. glibc code.